# Exception while acessing SFTP site: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Tags: c#, sftp, socketexception

I am newbie to C# and I am trying to accessing the SFTP using C# (Getting some code from internet). I tried this by writing below code. But I am getting exception as:

```
IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostByName(@"sftp://........");
// Get the IP address list that resolves to the host names contained in the 
// Alias property.
IPAddress[] address = hostInfo.AddressList;
// Get the alias names of the addresses in the IP address list.
```

"SocketException was caught: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"

I found a lot about this but failed to understand. Also I tried to connect the SFTP using [Tamir.SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) library but getting the same exceptions.

Please suggest some solution over it. I need this in my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you need to change:

```
IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostByName(@"sftp://server.address.com");
```

to:

```
IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostByName(@"server.address.com");
```

DNS doesn't know, nor care about the *protocol* (`sftp://`) that you're using to access the server, it only cares about the servers *name*.

**NOTE**: Microsoft considers the `Dns.GetHostByName` method to be obsolete and recommends that instead you use the [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostentry) method instead.